# Disabled Mouse/Keyboard on Win10 ASUS Mobo, due to removing ASUS program files

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, motherboard, mouse, reboot

I've been attempting to fix my fan control service, broken since Jan. I have a new installation of `AI Suite III`, from ASUS to install over an older version. In attempting to cleanup old files and start the service fresh, I deleted program files and registry entries of a couple of ASUS services.

I now regret this haha, as without this service mobo communication no longer has access to my mouse/keyboard via the USB I/O ports.

**Programs:**
`C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\...` and notably
`C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\AXSP\1.00.16\atkexComSvc.exe`

**Reg Entries:**
`HKEY_Local_Machine\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services` (A couple of things here, forget the names though.)

**System:** Windows 10 64bit, Asus H87 Mobo.

I'm running Ubuntu on another drive, so I can boot into that easily enough, but is there a way to remotely re-enable this seemingly essential service to make windows usable? It also seems that windows is hybernating the SSD drive I've installed it on which is painful for ubuntu to access....

Comment: Yes, Windows8 or newer have that annoying semi-hibernation feature but it should be possible to mount the partition read-only anyway. However, you cannot solve this from Ubuntu. You need to boot Windows media and repair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Summary:

1. Remove SSD/HDD.
2. Install into different PC (different MOBO)
3. Install remote control program such as Teamviewer
4. Setup remote access on account, and define a personal password, as user ID & remote access will change when you return to your original mobo. (ie `Extras -> Options -> Security` for Teamviewer v13.2.14327)
5. Trouble shoot 'Hardware and Devices' from troubleshoot menu. [Troubleshooting Launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44i6E.png)
6. When told about device not working, but windows can't fix it, open Device Manager, and uninstall device.
7. Troubleshoot hardware again, Windows should recognize the change in devices and install appropriate drivers. [Fixed it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11gcj.png)

## Details:

I attempted using a bootable Win10 Usb to try to repair the device. This had no success, and although I could peruse by the command line there was no possibility of reinstalling the relevant drivers.

This led me to think of other solutions. I had a teamviewer installation, however, I had not set it up for remote access.

At this point, I needed to resort to removing the SSD (Win10 instillation) and place it in another Mobo, where I could actually use peripherals. Using an ASRock mobo of another PC, I was able to access my instillation and activate remote use of teamviewer.

Bad luck struck again with teamviewer changing ID and requiring a new password (not known). You can get past this by setting up a consistent password for the teamviewer instillation (I also hibernated my PC rather than a completely fresh boot).

Upon gaining access, I installed the new fan drivers provided, hoping they'd also install relevant mobo drivers alongside. This was not the case.

I then began looking for how to fix the hardware issues. Running the 'Hardware and Devices' troubleshooter, I was given a selection to investigate connectivity to USB terminals. This troubleshooter failed though, as windows was entirely up to date, but just services had been deleted from registry.

Going to device manager, the device `USB ROOT HUB (USB 3.0)` was flagged as incorrectly functioning, and windows even listed that it was due to registry errors.

To proceed I uninstalled the device, ran the troubleshooter again, which successfully recognized the missing drivers, and re-initialized the appropriate services/reg-entries. Voila! Keyboard and mouse back and working.